# Deleting rows with duplicate info in columns

Tags: vba, excel, rowdeleting

I'm writing a code that copies data  from one sheet into another and I've got that function working fine. Now, I'm trying to code it to delete any rows that contain duplicate information based off that information's ID number in column F. Part of our process is to manually enter in column E when each row has been worked.

So my end goal is for the code to delete rows where column E is blank and column F is a duplicate. My code runs, but doesn't delete anything. I'm really hoping I'm just missing something ridiculously obvious.

```
For i = 1 To Range("f" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, 5).Value = "" Then 'if column E is blank on row i
        x = Cells(i, 6).Value
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(x, "F:F", 0)) Then '& if that row is a duplicate
            ActiveSheet.Range(x).EntireRow.Delete 'delete new duplicate row
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).EntireRow.Delete`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are a couple of errors that need to be addressed in your code. First, if you are looping over a range and deleting rows, it's best to start from the bottom and work your way up. This prevents issues where your iterator is on a row, that row gets deleted, and the loop essentially skips the next row.

Next, you are looking for a `Match` in column F of `x`, which contains a value from Column F. So, it will always return a value (itself, at the very minimum). Maybe try using a `COUNTIF` and seeing if it's greater than 1 may be a better option?

Next, you populated the variable `x` with the value in `Cells(i, 6)`, but then you try to use it as a range when deleting. Change your code to the following and see if it works:

```
For i = Range("f" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
If Cells(i, 5).Value = "" Then 'if column E is blank on row i
x = Cells(i, 6).Value
    If Application.Countif(Columns(6), x) > 1 Then '& if that row is a duplicate
    ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Delete 'delete new duplicate row
    End If
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Highly appreciate the added info/best practices details. I'd upvote for that alone. "Teach a man to fish..."

Answer (score 5):

Try it with,

```
For i = Range("f" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row to 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 5).Value = "" Then 'if column E is blank on row i
        x = Cells(i, 6).Value
        If Application.Countif(Columns(6), x) > 1 Then '& if that row is a duplicate
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete 'delete new duplicate row
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

You were trying to delete the row number *x*, not *i*. Additionally, everything was going to be matched once.

Comment: You beat me to the bunch. I need to type more quickly!!

Comment: @user3561813 you had a longer explanation ^_^

Comment: @findwindow maybe I can change my username to `verbosity`!

Comment: @user3561813 - I don't see any issue with similar answers being posted within a short timeframe and fw is correct; you took the time to expand on 'best practise' corrections like working bottom-to-top that I only corrected in code. The cream will rise to the top.

Comment: Ugh Batman, youtube blocked at work. But yeaaaaa, 3-3 now. Pay per view cage fight commencing. Please paypal tickets to my email kthxbye.

Comment: I just put him over! He's in the lead now!

Comment: @user3561813 I am trying to sell tickets and you ruin it. tsk tsk. Removing my upvote from you =P

Comment: See it's conversations like this that make me love, not just use, this site. ;)

Thanks for the assist. I'll test and confirm it works.

Comment: @TommyM Make sure you use your upvotes wisely! We need to make sure findwindow maximizes ticket sales

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the .RemoveDuplicates method? It's faster than looping around. Here's a rough outline on its use:

```
With Range
    .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(6), Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Here's the [msdn doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx) for the method, and [another page](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2015/2/24/vba-code-remove-duplicate-cell-values-or-entire-rows) with a more detailed implementation.  They should clear up any questions you might have.

Comment: Column E has to be blank as well as values in column F being duplicated. While using column E and F for the duplicate criteria **might** work, it could lead to false positives.